# Using Pandas, sorting based on two columns and displaying top 3

Tags: python, sorting, pandas

I have a dataframe with `states`, `counties`, and `populations` for each county.

I am trying to show the top three counties by population for each state. From there, I want to sum those three for each state, and then display the top three states by population.

```
census_df = pd.read_csv('census.csv')

df.sort_values(by=['STATE','POP'],ascending=[True,False])
```

This gives me the sort by `state` but is not sorting by `population`.

Am I going about this wrong? Even if I get the sort to work, I am unsure of how to start aggregating and showing beyond a simple `head()`.

Comment: What's the output of `census_df.POP.dtype`? `POP` should sort properly if its data type is `int` or `float`.

Comment: Once you are certain that the `POP` column is numeric, then do `df.sort_values(by=['STATE','POP'],ascending=[True,False]).groupby('STATE').head(3)`.